# (Erlang) Got error while parsing ecsda public key pem file

Tags: erlang, public-key, pem, ecdsa

I made private and public keys files as

```
openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -out gen.pem

openssl ec -in gen.pem -pubout -out gen.pub
```

then I checked .pub file

```
openssl pkey -in gen.pub  -pubin -text -noout

Public-Key: (256 bit)
pub: 
    04:fc:de:4f:2a:77:bd:c4:f2:74:2b:ba:b5:fc:85:
    e4:aa:96:a7:8e:86:14:bc:0d:fa:8e:d2:dd:50:3c:
    5d:fa:f4:07:f4:17:80:49:06:19:0c:72:03:63:4e:
    07:37:e9:10:64:c8:33:a4:a3:7e:26:d8:df:79:21:
    d7:2d:a6:01:80
ASN1 OID: secp256k1
```

After that start erl

```
erl
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.2] [source-e6dd627] [64-bit] [smp:3:3] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
```

After execution of commands

```
1>rr(public_key),
  {ok,RawData} = file:read_file("gen.pub"),
  Decoded = public_key:pem_decode(RawData),
  [public_key:pem_entry_decode(X) || X <- Decoded ].
```

I got exception

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 
                    {error,{asn1,{invalid_length,1}}}
     in function  public_key:der_decode/2 (public_key.erl, line 229)
```

I know that there are workarounds, but I'm wondering if I do something wrong or there are errors in public key modules ?

**UPD 1.**

When we look at result

```
{ok,#'SubjectPublicKeyInfo'{algorithm = #'AlgorithmIdentifier'{algorithm = {1,2,840,10045,2,1},
                                                           parameters = <<6,5,43,129,4,0,10>>},
                        subjectPublicKey = <<4,241,200,19,168,25,25,81,43,216,
                                             89,201,37,62,66,39,166,231,161,98,
                                             223,133,119,12,...>>}}
```

we can see next :

{1,2,840,10045,2,1} is oid of ecPublicKey http://oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.10045.2.1

parameters = <<6,5,43,129,4,0,10>>

```
'OTP-PUB-KEY':decode('EcpkParameters',<<6,5,43,129,4,0,10>>).
```

gives us

```
{ok,{namedCurve,{1,3,132,0,10}}}
```

and

```
pubkey_cert_records:namedCurves({1,3,132,0,10}).
```

gives us our source curve  - secp256k1, and

```
 subjectPublicKey = <<4,241,200,19,168,25,25,81,43,216,
                    89,201,37,62,66,39,166,231,161,98,
                    223,133,119,12,...>>
```

is public key itself. But this is workaround how I said before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your steps and it worked for me straight away:

```
g@crayon2:~/test % openssl ecparam -name secp256k1 -genkey -out gen.pem

g@crayon2:~/test % openssl ec -in gen.pem -pubout -out gen.pub
read EC key
writing EC key

g@crayon2:~/test % openssl pkey -in gen.pub -pubin -text -noout
Public-Key: (256 bit)
pub: 
    04:f1:c8:13:a8:19:19:51:2b:d8:59:c9:25:3e:42:
    27:a6:e7:a1:62:df:85:77:0c:ef:f7:0e:0e:19:93:
    df:e6:f5:42:66:7e:ee:02:07:76:85:19:a4:a8:2d:
    03:11:73:0c:b2:d4:4c:c7:0e:42:d3:30:b5:51:e3:
    97:45:f8:b5:6a
ASN1 OID: secp256k1

g@crayon2:~/test % erl
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V7.2.1  (abort with ^G)

1> rr(public_key).
['AAControls','ACClearAttrs','AccessDescription',
 'Algorithm','AlgorithmIdentifier',
 'AlgorithmIdentifierPKCS-10','AlgorithmIdentifierPKCS-8',
 'AlgorithmIdentifierPKCS5v2-0','AlgorithmIdentifierPKSC-7',
 'AlgorithmNull','AnotherName','AttCertValidityPeriod',
 'Attribute','AttributeCertificate',
 'AttributeCertificateInfo','AttributePKCS-10',
 'AttributePKCS-7','AttributeTypeAndValue',
 'Attributes_SETOF',
 'Attributes_SETOF_valuesWithContext_SETOF',
 'AuthorityKeyIdentifier','BasicConstraints',
 'BuiltInDomainDefinedAttribute','BuiltInStandardAttributes',
 'Certificate','CertificateList','CertificationRequest',
 'CertificationRequestInfo',
 'CertificationRequestInfo_attributes_SETOF'|...]

2> {ok,Data}=file:read_file("gen.pub").
{ok,<<"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAE8cgTqBkZUSvYWcklPkInpuehYt+Fdwzv\n9w4OGZPf5vVCZn7u"...>>}

3> Dec=public_key:pem_decode(Data).
[#'SubjectPublicKeyInfo'{algorithm = <<48,86,48,16,6,7,42,
                                       134,72,206,61,2,1,
                                       6,5,43,129,4,0,10,
                                       3,66,0,4,241,200,
                                       ...>>,
                         subjectPublicKey = not_encrypted}]
```

My OpenSSL version:

```
g@crayon2:~/test % openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1p-freebsd 9 Jul 2015
```

System is `FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE`. Erlang version is in the shell output above. The `gen.pub` key that it generated for me (if you want to try to load it) is:

```
g@crayon2:~/test % cat gen.pub
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EEAAoDQgAE8cgTqBkZUSvYWcklPkInpuehYt+Fdwzv
9w4OGZPf5vVCZn7uAgd2hRmkqC0DEXMMstRMxw5C0zC1UeOXRfi1ag==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Do you maybe want to paste your key so that I can try to load it?

**Edit:**

Sorry, I missed the last step. This seems to be a bug in the OTP code. The `der_decode/2` function is called with `KeyType` set to `ECPoint`, see the [`pem_entry_decode/1` function](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-18.2.4/lib/public_key/src/public_key.erl#L136). But [`der_decode/2` expects `Asn1Type`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-18.2.4/lib/public_key/src/public_key.erl#L223). Calling the `'OTP-PUB-KEY'` module directly seems to be working:

```
8> Bin = hd(Dec)#'SubjectPublicKeyInfo'.algorithm.
32> 'OTP-PUB-KEY':decode('SubjectPublicKeyInfo', Bin).
{ok,#'SubjectPublicKeyInfo'{algorithm = #'AlgorithmIdentifier'{algorithm = {1,
                                                                            2,840,10045,2,1},
                                                               parameters = <<6,5,43,129,4,0,10>>},
                            subjectPublicKey = <<4,241,200,19,168,25,25,81,43,216,
                                                 89,201,37,62,66,39,166,231,161,98,
                                                 223,133,119,12,...>>}}
```

However I am not sure if it returns anything sensible. Maybe worth raising a bug in OTP with the code that you posted in this question as steps to reproduce. Then at least someone competent would verify why it doesn't work. I am sure the steps you followed are fine and the types returned and passed to further functions are OK as far as [the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/public_key.html#pem_entry_decode-1) is concerned.

Comment: You missed the final step shown by the OP, which for your case you can run via `public_key:pem_entry_decode(hd(Dec)).` If you run that on your `gen.pub` you get the same error as the OP.

Comment: So how I thought this is not a feature this is a bug

Answer (score 0):

I found that lines in public_key.erl ( lines 136-137 )

```
'ECPoint' ->
     der_decode(KeyType, Key0)
```

have to be replaced with

```
'ECPoint' ->
     {{KeyType,Key0},der_decode('EcpkParameters', Params)}
```